# Path, directory and/or file name

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

What does the following message mean?

```
{"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."}
```

Is a file name this:

```
document1.doc
```

or is it this:

```
folder2\document1.doc
```

or is it this:

```
c:\folder1\folder2\document1.doc
```

Is a directory name this:

```
folder1
```

or is it this

```
folder1\folder2
```

or is it this:

```
c:\folde1\folder2
```

What's the path?  is it a directory, or all directories, or is it the drive letter, all directories, and the filename?

I am writing a program using .NET and it is giving me the error message above.

What I don't know is that 260 characters the limit for the full string, as in drive letter, folder names, and file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the full thing that can't be more than 260 characters long:

```
c:\folder1\folder2\document1.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

it is mentioned in the error that "`fully qualified name must be less than 260 chars`". and fully qualified address is concatenation of driver letters, one or more directories and the file name. so in this case fully qualified name will be

```
c:\folder1\folder2\document1.doc
```

and it must be less than 260 charaters